# $\lVert u\rVert_{L^{4}(\Omega)}^{4}\leq4\lVert u\rVert_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\lVert\nabla u\rVert_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

The problem is

> Suppose $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is open, $u\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$. Proof that$$\lVert u\rVert_{L^{4}(\Omega)}^{4}\leq4\lVert u\rVert_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\lVert\nabla u\rVert_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}.$$

What I have done:

> Since $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, assume first $u\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Integrating by parts shows$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t,y)u(t,y)\,dt=u^{2}(x,y)-\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t,y)u(t,y)\,dt.$$So$$\lvert u(x,y)\rvert^{2}=2\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t,y)u(t,y)\,dt\leq2\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left| \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t,y)\right| \cdot\lvert u(t,y)\rvert\,dt,$$ a similar discussion then shows$$\lvert u(x,y)\rvert^{4}\leq4\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left| \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t,y)\right| \cdot\lvert u(t,y)\rvert\,dt\cdot\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left| \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,t)\right| \cdot\lvert u(x,t)\rvert\,dt.$$Now use Schwarz's inequality,$$\lvert u(x,y)\rvert^{4}\leq4\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left| \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t,y)\right| ^{2}\,dt\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert u(t,y)\rvert^{2}\,dt\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left| \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)\right| ^{2}\,dt\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\left( \int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert u(x,t)\rvert^{2}\,dt\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Finally, integrating over $\Omega$ should give the conclusion, but I can't deal with the right hand side. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ does not imply $u \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$, the inclusion is the other way round. However if the result is true on $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ then it should be true on $H^1_0(\Omega)$ by density, so it's not too big a deal (I think?).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that! $H_{0}^{1}$ is indeed the closure of $C_{c}^{\infty}$, so I should take a sequence $u_{k}$ converges to $u$.

Comment: this isn't just the [Ladyzhenskaya's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladyzhenskaya%27s_inequality)

Comment: This post seems to answer your question? (thanks to @dezdichado for the name of the result) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237439/1104384

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps.